# Setting h1 from title/metadata

Tags: pdftex, pandoc

I have a bunch of .md failes. No 1 of them have an h1. They have instead a title in the metadata looking like this:

```
layout: layout.pug
navigationTitle: This is the title
title: This is the title
menuWeight: 800
excerpt:

enterprise: false
```

The title: is used as the h1 when used for web, but I need to specify as an h1 for Pandoc, in order to produce a TOC.

I have tried this:

```
$if(title-meta)$
        pdftitle={$title-meta$},
        h1={$title-meta$},
$endif$
```

But it doesn't' work.

I have also tried to include it in the style.yaml file, but nothing.

Is there a way to do this? I read through the Pandoc manual, and Latex templates, but I am not very familiar with all of it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was working with this `.md` files in an environment with bash and node scripts.

The resolution in this particular case was to:

- get the title of the front-matter of each files and insert it in the `.md` file as a H1 in a bash script.

This only worked, because none of the files had a H1.